# Problema con un toggler en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy diseñando mi pagina web, y le agregue un toggler con bootstrap al nav bar, luego de posicionarlo como yo queria, que es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al abrirlo, queda asi:

[image: introducir el código aquí]

No se porque sucede esto, el CSS para el posicionamiento es el siguiente:

```
@media(max-width:990px){
.button-margin{ /* Separacion entre los botones */
    margin-right:90px;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler{ /* Posicionamiento absoluto del toggler */
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
#button-styles{ /* Posicionamiento de botones al lado del toggler */ 
    position: absolute;
    right: 110px;
}

}
```

Y aca adjunto el navbar:

```
<nav class="margenes navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #cfeafd;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Veterinaria</a>
<button class="toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="margen-down navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Veterinari@s</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dueñ@s</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopta</a>
    </li>
    <div class="separador"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

¿Como puedo hacer que al presionar el toggler, los botones queden en la parte de encima, es decir, no se muevan?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres todos los botones a la derecha puedes envuélvalos en un `div`. El `nav` tiene `justify-content: space-between`. Entonces cuando usas el `div`, el `nav` tiene dos elementos. No cuatro. Y los elementos en el `div` van a irán a la derecha.

**Actualización**: agregué algunos css para los botones. Ahora los botones se quedan arriba a la derecha.

```css
 .btnWrapper {
   display: flex;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 10px;
 }

 @media(max-width:990px) {
  .button-margin {
    /* Separacion entre los botones */
    margin-right: 90px;
  }
  .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    /* Posicionamiento absoluto del toggler 
*/
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  #button-styles {
    /* Posicionamiento de botones al lado del toggler */
    position: absolute;
    right: 110px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="margenes navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #cfeafd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Veterinaria</a>
  <div class="btnWrapper">
    <button>Registrarte</button>
    <button>Ingrresar</button>
    <button class="toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="margen-down navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Veterinari@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dueñ@s</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopta</a>
      </li>
      <div class="separador"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Una opcion diferente:**
Creo que es más correcto usar los nombres de clase de Bootstrap para lograr lo que quieres. Con `navbar-right` y `btn-nav`.
Nota: los botones aparecen en la lista en pantallas pequeñas.

```html
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="margenes navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #cfeafd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Veterinaria</a>
  <div>
<button class="toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="margen-down navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Veterinari@s</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dueñ@s</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adopta</a>
  </li>
  <div class="separador"></div>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

  <li>
    <div class="btn-nav"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small navbar-btn" href="/register">Registrarte</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="btn-nav"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small navbar-btn" href="/register">Ingrresar</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hola @milmal, gracias por tu respuesta, el icono del toggler se queda arriba a la derecha, pero los botones de login y registro no, que puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola @HatoriHanso. Entendí mal. 
Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora me presenta otro problema, y es que cuando no esta en medida menor a 990px, los botones se me colapsan en el lado derecho, intente solucionarlo dandole un position absolute y acomodandolos pero no me deja, que es lo que puedo hacer?

Comment: @HatoriHanso estableciendo un valor de breakpoint diferente en tus reglas media query, se me ocurre por ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que es más correcto usar los nombres de clase de Bootstrap para lograr lo que quieres. Con `navbar-right` y `btn-nav`. Actualicé la respuesta

Comment: @HatoriHanso Pude lograr lo que querías usando algo de CSS en el div alrededor de los botones.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Como podria realizar eso?

Comment: @HatoriHanso me parece que la respuesta de milmal es correcta, si necesitas aclaraciones adicionales, puedes revisar por acá los breakpoints en la doc oficial de Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints

Comment: @milmal estoy teniendo unos problemas, los cuales son que al copiar y pegar tu codigo, me queda igual que antes, al presionar el toggler, los botones de registro y ingreso quedan en la parte inferior, y otras veces cuando logro modificarlo, el toggler no funciona, que puedo hacer?

Comment: Lo solucione sacando mi bundle.min.js y dejando solo las dependencias que escribiste en la cabecera del codigo, gracias!